# Driving in Croatia with European 1 year old driving license

Tags: driving-licenses, croatia

I'm planning to take a road trip to Croatia, and I'm wondering if I can enter the country with a European driver license that is less than one year old?

Comment: AFAIK there are no restrictions, so you're allowed to drive a car in Croatia if you have a valid EU driver licence

Comment: European license or EU license?

Comment: I have a driving license issued in Romania, that I was told is good as any other driving license issued in any of the European Union's countries.

Comment: And this is your own car or a loaned one, i.e. you're not planning to rent one? Rental companies often have restrictions on the age of the driver (not the license).

Comment: It will be my own car, not a rental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since at least 2009, Romania issues fully compatible EU driving licenses, credit card style and with the EU logo. With those, there should be no problem at all.

[image]